# Firebase function only runs if inside return statement

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I'm running a function that uploads an image to Firebase and sets the data to its respective user:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { FbUser } from 'src/app/common/fb-user';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';
import { NgxImageCompressService } from 'ngx-image-compress';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-info',
  templateUrl: './profile-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-info.component.scss']
})
export class ProfileInfoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public _auth: AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  currentImageUrl: string = "";

  async uploadPicture(e: any) {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    const filePath = this._auth.userData.uid
    const task = await this.uploadImage(filePath, file)

    if (task) {
      //Promise.resolve().then(() => window.location.reload())

      this.currentImageUrl = await this._auth._afstg.ref(task).getDownloadURL().toPromise();

      const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this._auth._afs.doc(`users/${filePath}`);
      const userData: FbUser = {
        uid: filePath,
        email: this._auth.userData.email,
        displayName: this._auth.userData.displayName,
        photoURL: this.currentImageUrl,
        emailVerified: this._auth.userData.emailVerified
      }
      return userRef.set(userData, {
        merge: true
      })
      alert("Image uploaded succesfully")
      window.location.reload()
    } else {
      alert("Error when uploading image, try again")
    }
  }

  async uploadImage(uid: string, file: any): Promise<string> {
    const fileRef = this._auth._afstg.ref(uid).child("profile-picture");

    // Upload file in reference
    if (!!file) {
      const result = await fileRef.put(file);

      return result.ref.fullPath;
    }
    return ""
  }
```

My problem is, as you can see I have an alert and a reload() after the return function, i tried to run userRef.set without the return function, but it just doesn't work, only way it works is if it is inside the return, and now I can't refresh the page after the data is modified, any ideas why or how I could reload after the return? Already tried try-finally and Prosimes.resolve, neither worked.

Comment: The `return` keyword always breaks out of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using a try-catch and await:

```js
  currentImageUrl: string = "";

  async uploadPicture(e: any) {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    const filePath = this._auth.userData.uid
    const task = await this.uploadImage(filePath, file)

    if (task) {
      //Promise.resolve().then(() => window.location.reload())

      this.currentImageUrl = await this._auth._afstg.ref(task).getDownloadURL().toPromise();

      const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this._auth._afs.doc(`users/${filePath}`);
      const userData: FbUser = {
        uid: filePath,
        email: this._auth.userData.email,
        displayName: this._auth.userData.displayName,
        photoURL: this.currentImageUrl,
        emailVerified: this._auth.userData.emailVerified
      }
      try {
        await userRef.set(userData, {
          merge: true
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error modifying user document", error);
      }
      alert("Image uploaded succesfully")
      window.location.reload()
    } else {
      alert("Error when uploading image, try again")
    }
  }

  async uploadImage(uid: string, file: any): Promise<string> {
    const fileRef = this._auth._afstg.ref(uid).child("profile-picture");

    // Upload file in reference
    if (!!file) {
      const result = await fileRef.put(file);

      return result.ref.fullPath;
    }
    return ""
  }
```